# Extracting hourly data from 15 minute data

Tags: r, timestamp, time-series, extract

I have a data frame with two columns, time and flow. The time interval for the time series is 15 minutes and I want to cut this time series so that the output time series has consistent one hour time intervals and the flow value from that hourly time stamp from the original data. How do I extract the hourly data?

Input:

```
structure(list(t = structure(c(1104555600, 1104556500, 1104557400, 
1104558300, 1104559200, 1104560100, 1104561000, 1104561900, 1104562800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "EST"), flow = c(18, 
18, 18, 18.125, 18.125, 18.125, 18.125, 18.125, 18.125)), .Names = c("t", "flow"), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

And for output I would want something like

```
time    flow
2005-01-01 00:00:00 18.000
2005-01-01 01:00:00 18.125
2005-01-01 02:00:00 18.125
```

Comment: Please provide example data and desired output in a form that is easy for us to read into R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your dataframe is a:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(a, grepl(":00:00",t))
```

Comment: not sure this solution will work if the first time point starts at 15 minutes and not 0 (in this case, if `a` is the dataframe the OP posted, run in it on `a[-1,]` to make sure)

Comment: Similarly, one could filter on `substr(t,15,16)=="00"`. It might be a tad faster since it only looks at the relevant substring.

Comment: @NicE with this data, it works, even if you swap the first two rows

Comment: yes but if you remove the first row it doesn't, swapping doesn't change anything since your filter will still find it. Your solution will be fine if all his data starts at 00

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cut` to get the hour in which each `t` variable is, and then just take the first element of every `cut` group. If `df` is your dataframe:

```
aggregate(df, list(cut(df$t,breaks="hour")), FUN=head, 1)[,-2]

#             Group.1   flow
# 2005-01-01 00:00:00 18.000
# 2005-01-01 01:00:00 18.125
# 2005-01-01 02:00:00 18.125
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't give any example, but from what I understand you simply want to keep every forth row.

In a data set with

```
time<- c(10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)
flow<- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
d <- data.frame(time,flow)

1    10    3
2    11    4
3    12    5
4    13    6
5    14    7
6    15    8
7    16    9
8    17   10
9    18   11
10   19   12
```

with

```
> d[seq(1, NROW(d), by = 4),]
```

you only keep every fourth row.

```
time flow
1   10    3
5   14    7
9   18   11
```

Comment: That is correct in a way but is there a way to do it so the program determines breaks the data itself by hourly time steps rather than breaking it by relative positions, i.e. 4 data points away from each other?